# how to pause angular interval timer when hovering over slide

Tags: javascript, css, angularjs

Is there a why i can place an eventlisterner to my code for the timer to stop pause when the mouse cursor hovers over one of the slides?

[flickr](http://plnkr.co/edit/7ju6keOTWIdP8cCU3c11?p=preview)

```
$scope.jobNotification = 0;

var timer;
$scope.startAuto = function() {
    timer = $interval(function(){
        $scope.jobNotification = ($scope.jobNotification + 1) % $scope.jobs.length;
    }, 5000);
};

$scope.isActive = function (index) {
    return $scope.jobNotification === index;

 };

$scope.showJobNotification = function (index) {
    if (timer){
        $interval.cancel(timer);
        $scope.startAuto();
    }
    $scope.jobNotification = index;
};
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use ng-mouseenter and ng-mouseleave directives to stop and start your timer, updated plunker http://plnkr.co/edit/09bf3T?p=preview:

```
$scope.stopAuto = function() {
  console.log('tickCtrl.stopAuto() triggered');
  if(timer) {
      $interval.cancel(timer);
      timer = undefined;        
  }
}

<ul ng-mouseover="stopAuto()" ng-mouseleave="startAuto()">
    <li data-ng-repeat="job in jobs" ng-show="isActive($index)">
        <h1>{{job.jobTitle}}</h1>
        <p>{{job.sector}}</p>
    </li>
</ul>
```